# Apache Thrift api to take cassandra snapshot

Tags: api, cassandra, snapshot

**Is there any api exist in apache thrift to take cassandra snapshot.**

Normally we have to use NodeTool.bat to take snapshot of keyspace.But **without using nodetool**
but **only by thrift api** is there any possibility **to take snapshot**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Taking a snapshot is only possible through cassandra's exposed JMX interface. This is the interface that nodetool uses, but you could write a custom java tool to access the JMX interface as well.

Comment: java script gets confused with JavaScript. :) Perhaps a Java util or Java class is better for clarity.